# How can we display different content in main section based on the selection of option from the sidebar in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-router

[image]

I am trying to design the page structure as shown in the image attached. On selection of the the option A I want to show the content related to the option selected from the sidebar with in the same page (without redirecting to new page). [React].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the ROUTING and rendering  components based on the url params :)
You click some tabs -> Your URL params are getting changed and differents components are getting rendered

```
 <Route path={`${path}`} exact component={Profile} />
 <Route path={`${path}/comments`} component={Comments} />
 <Route path={`${path}/contact`} component={Contact} />
```

Example I found -> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tabs-using-router-y6b92